# how to covert visualization table of app script to spread sheet google app script code

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have HTML web app where I have converted a spreadsheet to a HTML table. Now I would like to convert this HTML Table to a spreadsheet. Is it possible to convert it back to a spreadsheet?

You can say that I can directly make use of the spreadsheet but the problem is that I have **applied some filters**. Now whenever I apply a filter to a specific column, it will be displayed so now I want that **column to be moved to the new spreadsheet using google app script**

Here is my table, how can  convert this table to spreadsheet using Google App Script

[image: My Table Image Please go through]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I have edited your questions description for it to be more clear to others. I have fixed many grammatical mistakes and format issues. Also, please add some relevant code to your question so that other developers can better help you solve the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use two sheets for this example one sheet is named sht2tbl and the other sheet is named tbl2sht.  You need to have both ready to go when you run the code.

Here's sheet2table and table2sheet.gs:

```
function sheetToTable()//This produces a modeless dialog
{
  var s='';
  s+='<table width="100%">';
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sht=ss.getSheetByName('sht2tbl');
  var rng=sht.getDataRange();
  var rngA=rng.getValues();
  for(var i=0;i<rngA.length;i++)
  {
    s+='<tr>';
    for(var j=0;j<rngA[0].length;j++)
    {
      if(i==0)
     {
        s+='<th id="cell' + i + j + '">' + rngA[i][j] + '</th>';//put ids in each th
      }
      else
      {
        s+='<td id="cell' + i + j + '">' + rngA[i][j] + '</td>';//put ids in each td
       }
    }
    s+='</tr>';
  }
  s+=' </body></html>'
  var html=HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('html2body');//create output from file
  html.append(s);//and append s for the rest
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(html, 'Sheet to Table')
}

function getParams()//this gives the client side array dimensions
{
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sht=ss.getSheetByName('sht2tbl');
  var rng=sht.getDataRange();
  var A=[];
  A.push(rng.getWidth());
  A.push(rng.getHeight());
  return (A);//range width and height in an array
}

function putData(data)//this gets cell contents from the client side and displays them on another sheet named 'tbl2sht'
{
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sht=ss.getSheetByName('tbl2sht');
  var h=data.length;
  var w=data[0].length;
  var rng=sht.getRange(1,1,h,w);//create a range properly dimensioned
  rng.setValues(data);//use setValues to load sheet
}
```

This is the file htmltobody.html.  It's a lot easier to create javascript this way.   But I like to integrate the data creation with server side google script.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(function() {

    google.script.run
      .withSuccessHandler(getCellValues)//returns to get values from client side
      .getParams();//get width and height of data array
     });
      function getCellValues(A)
      {
        var w=A[0];
        var h=A[1];
        var data=[];
        for(var i=0;i<h;i++)
        {
          data[i]=[];
          for(var j=0;j<w;j++)
          {
             var s='#cell' + Number(i) + Number(j);
             data[i][j]=$(s).text();//use jquery text to get th and td values          
          }
        }
        google.script.run
          .putData(data);//send data to server side to load data in tbl2sht
      }
      console.log('My Code');//helps me to find code in chrome console
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
```

This is the sht2tbl which was use to create the modeless dialog:

[image]

This is the dialog that gets created:

[image]

And this is the data from the dialog displayed on a sheet named tbl2sht:

[image]